# How to clean the print heads of my HP printer?

Tags: hplip

I've got LaserJet P1005 that needs to have its print heads cleaned. hplip is installed with the gui but I don't find an option to clean the print heads. I'm on 12.04 64bit.

Comment: Do laser printers even have heads?

Comment: nope, they have a print roller. And if they get dirty, you generally just swap the whole unit I think

Comment: My toner is not empty yet as confirmed by hplip. But the pages come out extremely "dirty" with patches of toner all over them. If I pull out the whole unit I don't see any exposed areas that look like they need cleaning. Maybe a faulty unit?

Comment: In case someone finds this question and has a compatible printer, this can be done on Linux with the tool `hp-clean`: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/tech_docs/man_pages/clean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [This is not supported by the HPLIP driver for this printer](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_1005_series.html).

In most cases I might say that this is a feature omission, but in this case, because we're dealing with a LaserJet, I think it's just not a feature the hardware has.

Laser printers don't have "print heads". A laser etches into a drum covered in ink, toner tones things (alright, I'm a little sketchy on how they work exactly) and a static charge applies all of that to paper.

If you've got a mucky print, [there are things you can clean](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-clean-your-laser-printer.html) but it's very different lingo from inkjet printers. And it's all manual work.